# Apache POI and Null Pointer... csv converted to xlsx

Tags: java, excel, apache, csv, apache-poi

I am using Apache poi to parse through Excel 2010 files. I have a csv file that has the same content as one of my excel files. I opened my csv file in excel and saved it as an Excel workbook thinking that it should work in the program that I wrote but I keep getting null pointer exceptions. These happen on the lines of code that look up cells in the file when given a row number and a column number. I havent been able to find the cause for these null pointers and it works completely fine on my regular excel file. Is it just that the file was previously a csv file?

I am using the XSSF Usermodel

This is where it fails

```
RPCManager rpc = new RPCManager(
    sheet.getRow(row).getCell(indexes.name).toString(), 
    sheet.getRow(row).getCell(indexes.status).toString(), 
    sheet.getRow(row).getCell(indexes.customer).toString(), 
    sheet.getRow(row).getCell(indexes.site).toString(), 
    sheet.getRow(row).getCell(indexes.suite).toString(), 
    sheet.getRow(row).getCell(indexes.pod).toString(), 
    sheet.getRow(row).getCell(indexes.amps).toString(), 
    sheet.getRow(row).getCell(indexes.pp1).toString(), 
 ** sheet.getRow(row).getCell(indexes.pp2).toString(), **
    sheet.getRow(row).getCell(indexes.pp3).toString(), 
    sheet.getRow(row).getCell(indexes.cab).toString(), 
    sheet.getRow(row).getCell(indexes.rpcNum).toString(), 
    sheet.getRow(row).getCell(indexes.rpcPan).toString(), 
    sheet.getRow(row).getCell(indexes.rpcBr).toString(), 
    row);
```

"indexes.whatever" is just the index of the column and row is the row

This is a small part of the program that takes information in an excel file and writes an XML file. The Excel file has 2500-3000 rows and spits out around 70 XML files. The code above saves the needed information from the excel file to a class. This part of code is called around 2500 times. I'm guessing it broke on its first time around. It only gives the null pointer exception and the location where it happened which is on the line with the asterisks above.

Sorry I am kind of new to programming so I am pretty clueless

Comment: Without some code and where it fails, hard to tell. Are you reading the file using the Event model? We need more informations to be able to help you.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I added a some more information, sorry about that

Comment: Check, when you open your `CSV` file in Excel what you split the informations with (comma, spaces, etc). The application you use to open you file should let you pick what is between the data of your `CSV` file. Make sure you select the right ones before saving as this will impact the way your application behave.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau So right now the columns are separated by commas, is that the right one for it to be? I want to save it as an excel workbook so what should I do?

Comment: I have no idea how your file is and how it should be treated. You're the only one with the knowledge on your `CSV` file to make sure Excel opens it correctly and you can then save it.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Oh gotchya. It opens in excel just fine and it saves just fine and it all looks correct until it breaks my code. The only difference between the other xlsx file and the csv to xlsx file is that some of the cells arent colored but that shouldn't matter. hmm

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: @JimGarrison I added some more information, sorry I am very new to this, thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The null pointers occur because there is nothing in the worksheet at that row/column location.  You need to explicitly verify that there's a cell there before trying to fetch it.

What you do if a cell is null depends totally on how `RPCManager` handles missing data. If it can cope with nulls then something like the following might work:

```
int[]    cellNums = {indexes.name, indexes.status, ... ,indexes.rpcBr};
String[] cellVals = new String[cellNums.length];
XSSFRow r = sheet.getRow(row);
for (int i=0; i<cellNums; i++)
{
    XSSFCell c = r.getCell(cellNums[i]);
    cellVals[i] = c == null ? null : c.toString();
}
RPCManager rpc = new RPCManager(
    cellVals[0],
    cellVals[1],
    ...
    cellVals[13],
    row);
```

Otherwise you'll have to decide what to do when there is missing data.

Comment: Ah yes, okay I understand now. Thank you so much for your help, sorry for the inadequate information!